# Facebook Sharer not showing Link image, even if the debugger gives no error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Something weird is happening...
I would love to share this link: https://www.racebooking.net/it/moto/post/5812/giro-straordinario-di-fabrizio-perotti-a-bordo-del/  On Facebook, but the image is not showing up.

If i debug it Through the [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and "Fetch new scrape information" everything looks fine, i get no errors and the image is detected, but not showed in the link preview.

First time it happens, until some days ago everything worked fine with my website. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the current bug report:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/

Comment: For the first time in my life, i don't feel stupid :) This time it's not my fault! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tobi's answer: if your site provides both og:image, og:image:width and og:image:height, that image will be used even for the first share created. So don't forget the **og:image:width** and **og:image:height** meta tags.